# java find offset between NY and UTC

Tags: java, time, timezone

I am trying to get the current offset between NY(US/Eastern) and UTC.  How can I get this value regardless of what timezone my server is in, and anything else.  I just want the offset in milliseconds.  I am sure there is a quick way to do this, but I haven't found it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The offset between US/Eastern and UTC doesn't depend on what timezone your server is in, it depends on the date, and nothing more.

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=179 - it's either -4 or -5 hours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: this is not tested.

Using:

[Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

[TimeZone class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

```
//Get NY time zone instance
TimeZone ny_tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");

//Get NY calendar object with current date/time
Calendar ny_cal = Calendar.getInstance(ny_tz);

//Get offset from UTC, accounting for DST
int ny_offset_ms = ny_cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + ny_cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can get it as:

FOR EST:

```
    TimeZone est = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
    System.out.println("Offset ="+est.getRawOffset());
```

For PST:

```
    TimeZone pst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    System.out.println("Offset ="+pst.getRawOffset());
```

Comment: The OP asked for the current offset. This gets the raw offset. For locations that use daylight savings time during parts of the year, this is incorrect.

Comment: You need to add est.getRawOffset() + est.getDSTSavings() to account for daylight savings

Answer (score 0):

[Java API TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Use the getOffset() function to get the offset of one timezone and GMT, and then the other and GMT, then subtract them, and you are ready. Be careful though, someone did mention that this depends on the current date! And that is not trivial, since every day, for a couple of hours, the two time zones are in a different date! This can be important, if the two time zones are for example in different DST zones for those couple of hours (e.g. DST change times), which might lead to incorrect display

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getRawOffset() function to get the offset between any two timezone...
But you must understand one thing that the offset will be the difference between UTC and the given timezone..
Consider your server is in Canada,then the offset must be determined by the timezone difference between Canada and the users timezone..

```
    int offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone ('Asia/calcutta').getRawOffset() - TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
```

Here the 'TimeZone.getDefault()' is the timezone of the server ie)canada...so its needed to be subtracted to get the required offset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Geoff Montee's answer, but it didn't work for me. This is what ended up working out:

```
public static long getOffsetFromUTCInMilliseconds(TimeZone timezone) {
        long offset =  timezone.getOffset(DateTimeHelper.nowUTC().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)) + timezone.getDSTSavings();
        return offset;
    }
```

Conveniently, the answer returns a negative answer if the timezone is behind UTC (GMT-1, GMT-2, etc), and returns a positive answer if the timezone is ahead of UTC (GMT+1, GMT+2, etc).